# How to setup RabbitMQ for different environments?

Tags: rabbitmq

We have been working on a application using RabbitMQ which is installed in local development server. Now we want to move this application to integration and QA environments then the problem is do we need to setup RabbitMQ in different environments or is there any ways to have one central location for RabbitMQ with same exchange and queue names.

Comment: You setup rabbitmq with `apt-get install`. Why do you at first place create separated environments then want to tie them together? The point is that they are isolated from each other.

Comment: I have already done with the RabbitMQ setup in development environment and now we want to move the application which is using RabbitMQ to integration environment, so what are the ways to do this, as per my knowledge i wanted to setup RabbitMQ in integration and QA environment(One RabbitMQ server setup to one environment). Is there any better ways to do this?

Comment: have you consider http://www.docker.com/ ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can certainly have a central RabbitMQ instance/cluster that can be shared by different applications and different teams. If you want to go down this route, I'd recommend isolating data that belongs to each team from others' using [Rabbit's access control mechanisms](https://www.rabbitmq.com/access-control.html). **Virtual hosts** allow users to share Rabbit server/cluster resources without stepping on each other's queues.

If, for whatever reason, you decide to stick to a single virtual host in a shared environment, I'd advise against sharing the same exchange and queue names with other teams (or even other devs!) not least because of potential for conflict between the different parties' data. I say 'potential' because not knowing the architecture of your application and queues, there may not be a possibility for such a conflict so it's up to you to decide whether there would be a problem.

Finally, if the desire to share queues and exchanges with other teams is driven by concern over setup effort, I'd suggest automating queue configuration or building it into your application's startup routines to avoid headaches.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the your reply, i have completed this using virtual hosts. it's working perfectly. But one factor is there in concern is what about performance?

Comment: I don't know for sure but I wouldn't expect there to be an impact. Personally, I haven't noticed degradation in performance as a result of using virtual hosts but that's not to say there will never be one for any use case and load type.